# no callback for NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest on auto restart for VoIP app

Tags: ios, callback, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I am having an issue receiving any completion handler callback from either NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest or AFHTTPRequestOperation. I am developing a VoIP app which works fine when running in the background or foreground. However this problem is present when the app is killed by the OS in which it is then automatically restarted since it contains the voip background mode.

my investigation has found that it could be due to the thread exiting or runloop has stopped in which the callback is not received - I have tested sendSynchronousRequest and this receives the response.

my test code is below - completion handler not called on app auto restart:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:kHostTimeout];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"code %d",  code);
}];
```

Please shed some light on this issue as I may not be calling sendAsynchronousRequest correctly so that the callback is received?

It is weird as the network requests work if the user taps the app to open it.
Thanks for your help